# What is the way to update the AWS ssm parameter store values from the Spark scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, aws-ssm

I am able to write a code to get the values from the parameter store but can someone suggest to me the way to update the values of params

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient();
return ssmClient.getParameter(new GetParameterRequest().withName(paramName).withWithDecryption(decrypt)).getParameter().getValue();
```

I have tried to see any API exists from ssmClient as well.

Comment: Really? Did you not scroll down in the doc page to the "put" methods?

Comment: I thought the put method will create a new parameter. Does it update the existing parameter value?

Comment: @KonaLaxmanDeepak, [try using](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_PutParameter.html#systemsmanager-PutParameter-request-Overwrite) the `overwrite` parameter.